# Specify an app icon for phonegap build is not working

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap

I'm trying to change the default Cordova app icon for both ios and android using config.xml, but the build is using the Cordova logo as an icon and splash screen.

I don't have the Cordova iOS platform installed because I'm using PhoneGap build.

Here's the icon tag in **config.xml**

```
<icon src="res/icon.png" />
```

I put the icon inside `www/res/icon.png`
Is this a correct path?

Answer (score 0):

The path should point to `res/android/<DENSITY_TYPE>`

Here is example from [DOCs](http://stage.docs.phonegap.com/tutorials/configure/icons/android/):

```
<platform name="android">
  <icon src="res/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
  <icon src="res/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
  <icon src="res/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
  <icon src="res/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
</platform>
```

The `res` folder should lay under your root project, not under `www`